# AngularJs nested .success $scope variable is undefined

Tags: angularjs, rest, for-loop

I have a nested Http.get and a nested for loop. Why does my $scope variable becomes undefined?

```
$http.get('source')
  .success(function(res){
    $scope.myObject = res;

   for (var ctr=0; ctr< $scope.myObject.length; ctr++){
    for (var secCtr=0; secCtr< $scope.myObject[ctr].members.length; secCtr++){

          $http.get('source?_id=' + $scope.myObject[ctr].members[secCtr]._id)
              .success(function(response){
                      //here says $scope.myObject[ctr] is undefined
               }).error //some code here
      }
   }
}).error //some codes here
```

Comment: please elaborate more what you are doing..

Answer (score 1):

When the success callback function is evaluated, the loop has ended already. Thus your `ctrl` variable equals to `$scope.myObject.length`. Therefore `$scope.myObject[ctr]` is `undefined`.

To handle this you may use immediately invoked function expression like this:

```
for (var ctrl = 0; ctrl < $scope.myObject.length; ctrl++) {
    (function(myCtrl){
        $http.get(...).success(function() {
            console.log(myCtrl);
        });
    })(ctrl);
}
```

Calling this anonymous function on each iteration with `ctrl` would copy it into `myCtrl` variable and this one will hold a proper value for your callback.